# Place pieces of a file into a HashMap - Java

Tags: java, file, hashmap

I am reading in a file and want to store the file up until certain words, in this example 'yes' into a `HashMap of < Integer, document >.` But I am stuck with the `HashMap`, this is my train of thoughts.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filename.txt"));  
String line;     
int i = 0;
     while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {  
       if (!line.startwith("yes");{
         //add line to hashMap[i]
         i++;
        }

  System.out.println(hashMap[i]);  
}
```

How can I add my text until 'yes' into the `HashMap`?

Answer (score 1):

You use HashMap to store key,value pairs with unique keys.

You could certainly split your line on somthing:

`split_line = line.split(delimiter);`

and store:

`\** I am being unsafe here. You should probably check for null and type. *\

  hashmap.put( new Integer(split_line[0]), split_line[1]);`

but is this what you want to do?

Comment: I thought it was more like `map.put(i, line)`, but `i` would need to be an Integer, so you'd end up with `map.put(new Integer(i), line)`, but that's my take on in :P

Comment: I am using the HashMap because I want key, value pairs with unique keys. In this whole document I am reading in, I'd like to split it on certain words or tags.

Comment: Yes, @MadProgrammer, I think that is more what I am looking for.

Comment: You are right. I corrected that to Integer. Jo- pay attention to types, and also keep in mind that if keys are not unique values will get silently overriten in the map. You could use different data structure if you want repetitions.

Comment: @Edmon +1 for a nice suggest though ;)

Answer (score 0):

If your key in the Map is going to be integer with values from 0 to n, then you do not need a map but a List.

```
 List<String> goodWords = new ArrayList<String>();
 while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {  
       String[] words = line.split(" ");
       for (String str : words) {
           if (!"yes".equals(str)) {
               goodWords.add(str);
           }
       }
 }
```

Comment: I am still trying to figure out Java. I hope this is not a stupid question but how do I look in that list for example on the third document where word "yes" has split it? Why a using a list?

Comment: @Jo- You said that you want words added into your Collection until the word "yes"; this means that yes will not be in the Collection. However, if "yes" would be in the Collection then in order to find its place you should call the methods goodWords.indexOf("yes"). You should use a list because it has the same functionality than a Map<Integer, Value> with the integer from 0 to n; only the list is faster (there is no hashing).

Comment: thank you for that explanation why using the list. I'll look into .indexOf().

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand what you want to store in the HashMap actually. Can you be a bit more specific?

Here is how you can do it with **Scanner** - which I like more then simply parsing line after line.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    StringBuilder responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    File file = new File("/Users/eugene/Desktop/MyFile.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    scanner.useDelimiter("yes");
    while(scanner.hasNext()){
        responseBuilder.append(scanner.next());
        break;   
    }
    System.out.println(responseBuilder.toString());
}
```

}

Comment: I want to store unique values to every piece of text until a certain tag, I thought using a HashMap would be the best way, for example HashMap<Integer, String>, where the Integer is the unique value and String is the piece of text.

Comment: @Jo- yup seems like a good way to do things. The thing is if you want to split this document based on more keywords : "yes", "no", "good"... etc. Then the best thing to do (IMO) would be to use a Matcher and groups for that. Also you should think about cases when there are two "yes" for example or even better "yesSir" which should or should not be considered a token in the file?